# WCF Message Security with Mutual Certificates: Body not encrypted

Tags: c#, wcf, encryption

I've configured a WCF client that is hosted in IIS but cannot seem to get the message body to encrypt.

The error message returned from the service indicated that the message body was not encrypted.

I implemented a MessageInspector and can see that the message is not encrypted.  But given what code and configuration I have in place this is not really in line with my expectations.

So how do I guarantee that the message body is encrypted?

What steps will absolutely ensure that it happens?

Comment: show your configuration

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?